# Error: File to import not found or unreadable - importing scss with Webpack

Tags: css, webpack, sass

This is my config. It's a fresh setup, so it's very clean.

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    },
    extensions: [
      '.scss',
      '.js',
    ],
  },

  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.js'),
```

In `@/ui/style/base.scss` I have:

`@import '@/ui/style/variables.scss';`

Error message:

`Error: File to import not found or unreadable: @/ui/style/variables.scss.
    at options.error (/Users/andy/dev/chess.com/client/relay/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:291:26)
 @ ./src/index.js 2:0-54 4:32-35`

I've also tried:

`~@/ui/style/variables.scss
~@/ui/style/variables
@/ui/style/variables`

The only thing that works is using a relative path. All other assets (`.js`) are loaded correctly using the `@` alias.